# Hide a div only if it contains some specific words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that there are a lot of divs with same class which are displaying content dynamically as links. How could I remove/hide only those divs which contains the words e.g Sport, Television, Airline?

e.g

```
<div class="ns2-category">
    <a href="#">Sports</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
    <a href="#">Sports</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
    <a href="#">Magazine</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
    <a href="#">Airlines</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
    <a href="#">Television</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
    <a href="#">Other</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this a server side responsibility ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use javascript code below :

```js
$("div.ns2-category:has(a:contains('Sports'))").hide();
$("div.ns2-category:has(a:contains('Sports'),a:contains('Television'))").hide(); // either one OR two
```

Edit : add class name with div, for multiple

Comment: Wow, my answer below just blow compared to this one :D Good job.

Comment: you don't actually need `has` and check for `a` tag unless you need to make sure the word should be inside anchor tag... `$("div:contains('Sports')").hide();`should work, faster and readable. anyways +1

Comment: you can use jQuery 1.5.2 and above. @GregoryCh

Comment: it was added on jquery Version 1.4 so ny version after that should have it

Comment: @DipaliVasani no problem.. :)... nice answer but :contains is case sensitive ( you can add other function to make it caseinsesitive though)  anyways happy coding.. :)

Comment: I used it but it hide whole my webpage :)

Comment: @DipaliVasani and what about if I want to hide and those divs that has another word like Television? I mean in case that I want to hide divs that have different words, more than one. As thread's example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ns2-category a').each(function(i, v) {
        if(v.html().indexOf('Sport') != -1 || v.html().indexOf('Television') != -1 || v.html().indexOf('Airline') != -1) {
             v.parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Try this.

Basically I am iterating through all the divs with the calss and checking if the contents of them have the strings you specified. If so, I remove them.

Comment: in which JQuery library?

Comment: Any jQuuery version should support this, there is nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```js
// the words that you want to hide an element based upon:
var words = ['Sports', 'Television', 'Airline'];

// selecting the relevant elements:
$('div.ns2-category').filter(function() {
  // the text contained within the <a> element, with
  // leading/trailing white-space (if any) removed:
  var text = $(this).find('a').text().trim();

  // if the words array contains the found text:
  return words.indexOf(text) > -1;
// we hide the element (though remove() could be called):
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ns2-category">
  <a href="#">Sports</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
  <a href="#">Sports</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
  <a href="#">Magazine</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
  <a href="#">Airlines</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
  <a href="#">Television</a>
</div>
<div class="ns2-category">
  <a href="#">Other</a>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim/).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.ns2-category:has(a:contains('Magazine'))").hide();    
$("div.ns2-category:has(a:contains('Magazine'),a:contains('Television'))").hide();
```